# SQL Server Agent cannot access services on remote computer

Tags: sql-server, sql-agent-job, sql-agent

I have a job I need to set up for a client that checks the status of services on local and remote servers.

This is called from a SQL agent cmdexec step to a .bat file on a remote server share.

The only problem is that it can open services to check them on the local server, but trying to open services on remote servers creates an exception access denied message.

> Unhandled exception: Error occurred while checking the service: Systm.InvalidOperationException: Cannot open  on computer : --> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied.

If I run the bat file from the same server that SQL is on in a command prompt window, it works successfully.

What do I need to change to get this to work?

Comment: Is the agent running under a local or domain service account?

Comment: running locally. thanks, I'll give that a try and run it as a domain account

Comment: Adding that you can also run SQL Agent CMDEXEC job steps under a proxy account instead of the SQL Agent service account.

Comment: The effective user must have the permissions on the server it is attempting to access. If left unchanged it will be the user which the SQL Agent service is running as.